# Do LLM or Machine Learning models with a large number of classes employ standard cross entropy?

Tags: neural-networks, cross-entropy, large-language-models

In language modeling, the next token is predicted from the entire vocabulary during inferenc. However, when training models with large vocabularies or many different classes, standard cross entropy can be suboptimal due to its computational expense and sparsity of optimization. Are there any tricks or relevant papers that people use to address this issue?